# DefaultTokenServices fail to store enhanced refresh token when refreshAccessToken method is invoked

Tags: spring, spring-security-oauth2

In contrast to the `createAccessToken` method where the enhanced version of the refresh token is saved, the `refreshAccessToken` method saves the refresh token without enhancements.

I believe the behaviour should be something on these lines:

```
OAuth2AccessToken accessToken = createAccessToken(authentication, refreshToken);
    tokenStore.storeAccessToken(accessToken, authentication);
    // In case it was modified
    refreshToken = accessToken.getRefreshToken();
    if (refreshToken != null) {
        tokenStore.storeRefreshToken(refreshToken, authentication);
    }
    return accessToken;
```

Can this be considered a bug?

I created an issue for this https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/issues/511